# Having a subclass accept a reference to a parent in a constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, class-hierarchy

I have a class hierarchy that can be simply put like this:

```
struct Parent {
    Parent() { }
    Parent(Parent& p, std::string s) { }

private:
    // I want this class to be non-copyable
    Parent(const Parent&);
};

struct Child : public Parent {
    Child() { }
    Child(Parent& p) : Parent(p, "hi") { }
};
```

When I try to create two instances like this:

```
Child c1;
Child c2(c1);
```

I get the following error from Clang:

```
test.cpp:37:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'Child'
        Child c2(c1);
              ^  ~~
test.cpp:30:8: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
struct Child : public Parent {
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I want this class to be non-copyable, so is there a way to have the `Parent&` overload called instead of the copy constructor? I know why it behaves the way it does but I am looking for a workaround. I would like `Child(Parent& p)` to be called without having to cast it.

I get this error in [GCC](http://ideone.com/P0VT5) and Visual Studio as well. I don't get it with Intel's compiler though, but the consistent behaviour of the other three seem to indicate that it's wrong and the others are right.

Comment: So are you asking for a workaround or why it doesn't work?

Comment: @ildjarn I know exactly why it doesn't work, I need a workaround. Sorry, I'll edit it to make that more clear.

Comment: There's simply no way to make a constructor that has higher overload precedence than the copy constructor when passing a cv-qualified `Child&`. You need to go for casting, type erasure, factory functions instead of public constructors, or static polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're relying on the auto-generated copy constructor of the Child while making the copy constructor of the parent inaccessible. What seems to be happening is that the auto-generated copy constructor for Child is trying to call the copy constructor for the parent, but it can't because it's private.

If you don't want to add in a copy constructor, it looks like you need to either explicitly cast c1 to  parent reference:

```
Child c2(static_cast<Parent&>(c1));
```

or declare copy constructor for Child.

Apart from that, I don't believe there is a workaround.

Comment: I know that would fix it but I don't want this class to be copyable.

Comment: You can still make the child copy constructor private and provide no definition.

Comment: @Collin : Then it would merely be a linker error instead of a compiler error; not really a solution.

Comment: @Collin : That still needs a cast in order to work; that's no improvement on not declaring the copy constructor in the first place.

Comment: Updated the answer once more to clarify that it will work without declaring a copy constructor in the child.

Comment: @carleeto if you declare it private in the child class, then you just get an error saying `Child(Child&)` is private

Comment: @SethCarnegie : agreed. The child constructor cannot be private. It must be accessible (public)

Comment: I have decided to change the interface for my class because even if I could get this to work, I realise it would make the syntax `Child c2 = c1` which I don't want. So I will mark this as the answer even though it doesn't solve my problem because it is correct as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

You say that you don't want your class to be copyable.

You also say in your question that you want the following snippet to work:

```
Child c1;
Child c2(c1);
```

Those requirements are contradictory.